# SML: get index of item in list

Tags: list, indexing, sml

I'm new to SML and I'm attempting to get the index of an item in a list.  I know that using List.nth will give me the value of an item at a index position, but I want the index value.  There may even be a built in function that I'm not aware of.  In my case, the list will not contain duplicates so if the item is in the list I get the index, if not it returns ~1.  Here is the code I have so far.  It works, but I don't think it is very clean:

```
val L=[1,2,3,4,5];
val m=length L-1;
fun Index(item, m, L)=if m<0 then ~1 else
    if List.nth(L, m)=item then m else Index(item,m-1,L);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? I believe there is no standard function that does this explicitly, at least not in the List structure. As for cleaning up your code, I would suggest 1) using Option or an exception instead of returning `~1`, 2) hide the parameter `m` by wrapping the function in an outer function, 3) use pattern matching on `m` to eliminate one conditional (`if m < 0 ...`)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  The question was really, "What's the best way to do this?". It would be nice not to pass m into the function since it depends on the length of L anyways, but like I said I'm new to SML and not sure how to combine the two.  The reason for the code is; I have two lists of different types that are related.  The update of an item in list one requires the update of an item in the same position in the list two.  I believe the List structure might provide something like this with "zip", but this is working for now.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on my previous comment, I suggest some changes for an implementation that fits better in the ML idiom:

```
fun index(item, xs) =
  let
    fun index'(m, nil) = NONE
      | index'(m, x::xr) = if x = item then SOME m else index'(m + 1, xr)
  in
    index'(0, xs)
  end
```

The individual changes are:

- Have `index` return a value of type `int option`. `NONE` means the item is not in the list, `SOME i` means it is in the list, and the index of its first occurrence is `i`. This way, no special values (`~1`) need be used and the function's intended usage can be inferred from its type.
- Hide the parameter `m` by renaming the function to `index'` and wrapping it into an outer function `index` that calls it with the appropriate arguments. The *prime* character (`) often indicates auxiliary values.
- Use pattern matching on the list to get to the individual elements, eliminating the need for `List.nth`.

Also note that most commonly, function and variable names begin with a lowercase letter (*index* rather than *Index*), while capital letters are used for constructor constants (*SOME*) and the like.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. I have been seeing this idiom several times here in SO and couldn't understand the purpose of naming both inner and outer functions with same name. I tried to google it but it's hard to search for something you don't know what is it called. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a simpler and less efficient version of this `index` function. I agree that it is not as desirable to use exceptions rather than `int option`, and that it is not tail-recursive. But it is certainly easier to read and thus may serve as learning material:

```
fun index (x, []) = raise Subscript
  | index (x, y::ys) =
    if x = y then 0 else 1 + index (x, ys)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fun index(list,n)=
= if n=0 then hd(list) else index(tl(list),n-1);
val index = fn : 'a list * int -> 'a

index([1,2,3,4,5],2);
val it = 3 : int

index([1,2,3,4,5],0);
val it = 1 : int
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!